# Assign DNS name to Docker Swarm containers with public IPv6

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to understand how I would set up a Docker container (running in Swarm mode) with publicly available IPv6.

I know Docker Swarm uses mesh routing, but I don't quite understand how I can dynamically assign DNS names to addresses.

As an example, let's say I want to run a Git server (with HTTP 80 443 and SSH 22) on `git.example.com` and a regular web server at `example.com` (with HTTP 80 443). Both have public IPv6 addresses, but I don't want to hard-code the IPv6 address (for example at CloudFlare). After all, this is DevOps!

How would I go about doing this? I assume I need to run my own DNS server for this.

**Note**: After doing some more research, it seems this is possible with the [Docker HTTP Routing Mesh (HRM)](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.1/guides/admin/configure/use-domain-names-to-access-services/) which is unfortunately only part of the Enterprise Edition. Does anyone know a similar, open-source approach to this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "publicly available" is on the public internet it will be difficult.

DNS isn't really that reactive to changes and is challenging to run in a secure fashion on the public internet.

It also depends on what protocol you are running, because of an oddity around SRV records where pre-existing protocols were excluded from supporting it in the RFC.

But in general the public and the private solution I would implement are similar with an additional layer for a public internet solution. (assuming no use of a 3rd party or geo specific answers)

On the internet edge use [Unbound DNS server](https://www.unbound.net/) on the edge, and have it relay queries to [consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) which would handle service registration.

If this is for private usage this would allow for some data-center awareness and fail-over.

If it is just for internal use you can just use consul and either configure your internal DNS servers to delegate subdomains or forward to the default domain.

Comment: Direct DNS changes could be problematic if you're making AAAA record updates at a rapid rate (faster than cache expiring or a zone transfer from a private BIND to public NS server).  What's the expected DNS update frequency?